# KeyNotFoundException in GraphQL .net Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, graphql

I am using below with two `DbContext`s:

https://github.com/SimonCropp/GraphQL.EntityFramework

I get this error:

> GraphQL.ExecutionError: Error trying to resolve project.
>
> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'Models.Master.Project' was not present in the dictionary.
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
>
>   at IncludeAppender.AddIncludes[TItem,TSource](IQueryable`1 query, ResolveFieldContext`1 context) in C:\\projects\\graphql-entityframework\\src\\GraphQL.EntityFramework\\IncludeAppender.cs:line 20
>
>   at
>   GraphQL.EntityFramework.EfGraphQLService.<>c__DisplayClass21_0`2.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\graphql-entityframework\src\GraphQL.EntityFramework\EfGraphQLService_Queryable.cs:line 80
>
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown
>
> at GraphQL.Instrumentation.MiddlewareResolver.Resolve(ResolveFieldContext context)
>   at GraphQL.Execution.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteNodeAsync(ExecutionContext context, ExecutionNode node)
>
> End of inner exception stack trace

When I try to add two models of two `DbContext`s as following in `startup.cs` (in following, if I remove second line, then it works perfectly. But that I need for my second `DbContext`).

```
EfGraphQLConventions.RegisterInContainer(services, ProjectDataContextBuilder.ProjectModel); //This is creating issue as of now. wasn't issue when checked with my and your.
EfGraphQLConventions.RegisterInContainer(services, MasterDataContextBuilder.MasterModel);
```

`DataContextBuilder` classes are as follows:

```
static class MasterDataContextBuilder
{
    static MasterDataContextBuilder()
    {
        using (var masterDataContext = InMemoryContextBuilder.Build<ecdiscoMasterContext>())
        {
            MasterModel = masterDataContext.Model;
        }
    }

    public static IModel MasterModel;
}

static class ProjectDataContextBuilder
{
    static ProjectDataContextBuilder()
    {
        using (var projectDataContext = InMemoryContextBuilder.Build<ecdiscoProjectContext>())
        {
            ProjectModel = projectDataContext.Model;
        }
    }

    public static IModel ProjectModel;
}
```

**Note**: In error. Project is model of `MasterDbContext`.

Another `DbContext` is Project. which is separate per tenant. So that is `ProjectDbContext` (which doesn't have `Project` model).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is fixed in version 6 https://github.com/SimonCropp/GraphQL.EntityFramework/blob/master/doco/configuration.md#multiple-dbcontexts

Some extra text to get over the silly 30 char min